# How to change color of the background and sync it to another class (Android Studio)

Tags: javascript, java, android, class, colors

So I created a settings class for my project where I can change the color of the background. The problem is when I return back to home the settings doesn't sync or save. What can I do to sync it to my other class?

Comment: Why do you have both javascript and java tags? I'm assuming you know which language you are programming it. Java has no relationship to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you saved your settings in shared preferenced. You can override your OnResume method in your activity and load your settings and change the background there.

Comment: can you elaborate more?